# Tensorflow hash error during installation (pip)

Tags: tensorflow, pip, raspberry-pi

I am trying to install tensorflow on in a Docker Container on a RB Pi Zero.
I get some weird hash-error, see below. What can I try next?

```
root@123456:/# sudo pip3 install --no-cache-dir tensorflow
Collecting tensorflow
  Downloading https://www.piwheels.org/simple/tensorflow/tensorflow-1.14.0-cp35-none-linux_armv6l.whl (94.2MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 94.2MB 888kB/s
THESE PACKAGES DO NOT MATCH THE HASHES FROM THE REQUIREMENTS FILE. If you have updated the package versions, please update the hashes. Otherwise, examine the package contents carefully; someone may have tampered with them.
    tensorflow from https://www.piwheels.org/simple/tensorflow/tensorflow-1.14.0-cp35-none-linux_armv6l.whl#sha256=cba22b6d9a3e7a92c07e142bd5256c9773fd20c18090cb1d222357d3b3028655:
        Expected sha256 cba22b6d9a3e7a92c07e142bd5256c9773fd20c18090cb1d222357d3b3028655
             Got 65c83ef17cd950cf40d021070f3e7e1fa99499a99815c15495920ddc3440a98f
```

No space issues:

```
root@123456:/# df -h /
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay          29G  9.8G   19G  36% /
```

I've tried to remove files in 'rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/partial' and performed apt-get update&upgrade, but with same result. What can I try next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update

[The hashes were fixed](https://github.com/piwheels/packages/issues/32#issuecomment-600864275), so the hash mismatch warning should be gone now.

#### Original answer

Unfortunately, this is a common issue with https://www.piwheels.org when large wheels are uploaded. If you take a close look at the [simple URLs of `tensorflow` wheels](https://www.piwheels.org/simple/tensorflow/), you'll notice that the wheels

```
tensorflow-1.14.0-cp36-none-linux_armv7l.whl
tensorflow-1.14.0-cp36-none-linux_armv6l.whl
tensorflow-1.14.0-cp35-none-linux_armv7l.whl
tensorflow-1.14.0-cp35-none-linux_armv6l.whl
tensorflow-1.14.0-cp34-none-linux_armv7l.whl
tensorflow-1.14.0-cp34-none-linux_armv6l.whl
```

all have the same sha256 hash in download links, which means the hashes are just wrong. The workaround is to download the wheels to and install from disk:

```
$ wget https://www.piwheels.org/simple/tensorflow/tensorflow-1.14.0-cp35-none-linux_armv6l.whl
$ pip install tensorflow-1.14.0-cp35-none-linux_armv6l.whl
```

I have also reported wrong hashes [here](https://github.com/piwheels/packages/issues/32), so the issue will be fixed sooner or later.